# wprintf behaviour with MingW64

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64

I've been scratching my head on a very odd issue.
See sample code  below:

**test_c.c**

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stringapiset.h>
    
int  main (int argc,  char   **argv)
{
  const char mystr[] = "The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

  wchar_t wideName[MAX_PATH];
  int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, mystr, -1, wideName, MAX_PATH-1);

  wprintf( L"Length = %d - String = %s\n", len, wideName );

  return 0;      
}
```

Compilation command quite straightforward:

`gcc -static test_c.c -o test_c.exe`

The first odd thing that's happening, is that the result I get is different depending on the toolchain I'm using:

1. With [x86_64-6.3.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2.7z](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/6.3.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-6.3.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2.7z/download), [x86_64-7.3.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/7.3.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-7.3.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0.7z/download), or [x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z/download) (all using older Ming-W64 releases), I get as expected:

`Length = 39 - String = The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog`

2. With [winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-10.2.0-llvm-10.0.1-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1](https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/releases/download/10.2.0-10.0.1-8.0.0-r1/winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-10.2.0-llvm-10.0.1-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1.7z) or [winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.2.0-llvm-12.0.1-mingw-w64-9.0.0-r1](https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/releases/download/11.2.0-12.0.1-9.0.0-r1/winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.2.0-llvm-12.0.1-mingw-w64-9.0.0-r1.7z) (using MingW-64 8.0.0 and 9.0.0) I get this instead:

`Length = 39 - String = T`

To add to this strangeness, if I make it a C++ file now:

**test_cpp.cpp**

```
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <cwchar>
#include <stringapiset.h>

int  main (int argc,  char   **argv)
{
  const char mystr[] = "The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

  wchar_t wideName[MAX_PATH];
  int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, mystr, -1, wideName, MAX_PATH-1);

  wprintf( L"Length = %d - String = %s\n", len, wideName );

  return 0;      
}
```

and if I use the same compilation command:

`g++ -static test_cpp.cpp -o test_cpp.exe`

then I get a something even more strange:

1. With all the toolchains mentioned above, I get:

`Length = 39 - String = T`

2. But, if I uncomment the #include <stdio.h>, then I get something similar to the plain old C example (result varies with the toolchain)

Am I doing something wrong ?
Is there a way to fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a way to fix this ?

Yes. `%s` is for printing `char*`. To print `wchar_t*`, use `%ls`.

Comment: I can't believe it was as simple as that.... Thanks a lot !
This is what happens when you try to learn from examples.... and the examples are wrong.